# Does my Xcode provisioning profile need my private key to be used on another mac?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

Do I really need to export the private key from my computer and pass it together with provisioning profile to my teammate for him to build IPA file? If so, where do I get the private key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you really do need to export it, export it from Keychain Access.

Here's a screenshot of how it looks:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12/keychain-access-3-export-private-key

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering this question. But I just realized that I used my own IOS dev account to develop the app...Now i transfer the code to another guy, so, may i ask should I give him my private key? Or should i ask him to use his? I am a little confused..

Comment: @nanshi, whose store do you want to submit the app to?  Your account, or his?  If yours, you must use your key and profile.  If his, use his.

Comment: I would consider it secure.  Also, you didn't mention, is it the key you setup for development or distribution?  For development, I wouldn't really care, but for distribution, it is sensitive such that it's really the most important central piece for signing an app as you

Comment: thank you guys for your quick help and great answer! :) now i understand this. Yes, i should then ask my boss to provide an account to avoid the accident that my coworker or i submit the app using his/my account :) For development now, if it's secure, i will pass my key to him then :)